# I accidentally deleted part of my code in c++ Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I deleted part of my code, and accidentally saved.

I tried looking at my history and my source explorer, but those were both greyed out. 
Help?
Thanks

Comment: Did you close Visual Studio after saving? If it's still open can't you just undo the changes?

Comment: Might be time to A) learm to use `git` & B) Go look for your latest backup & C) Look into data recovery tools for you filesystem type

Comment: If you can't just ctrl+z it, and you don't have the code saved somewhere else (git), you're probably hooped. This has happened to everyone at some point or another. You're probably just going to need to rewrite it.

Comment: Google it : ntfs restore deleted files

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you can pull your deleted code out of the void, but you should look into version control software, like Git, to keep a lock on each version of your programs. I know it doesn't solve your problem now, but it will help a ton in the future if you make changes often!

Answer (score 2):

Go to "Edit" → "Undo" to undo recent changes.

Or, go into your version control system's log and revert to an older committed version.

Or, restore from one of your off-site backups.

Answer (score 0):

The most important was already said. However, here some relevant complements:

1. The *Edit* -> *Undo* (or <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>) has to be done **file by file** if you have several files in your project.
2. The *Undo* works after a *Save*, provided that you've set the focus in the editor's window (and not the solution explorer's).  However, once you've left Visual Studio, it's lost forever!
3. The ***[AutoRecover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/autorecover-environment-options-dialog-box)*** setting  in the *Environment* section of the *Option* dialog box ensures that a copy of your unsaved work is saved every couple of minutes and keep it a couple of days (in your document folder under *Visual Studio 20xx\Backup Files...*).  Unfortunately, it is designed to protect you against a crash; so the files are removed when you save, and it won't help you (I mention it only in case you were aware of the backup files and hoped to get a solution with it).
4. If you're working with windows 10 and have activated the [file history backup](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2974385/windows/how-to-use-windows-10s-file-history-backup-feature.html) you may luckily look at older versions in the explorer.  This will not help if you have done changes and deleted them without a backup in-between (e.g within one hour at least).
5. You may not like this suggestion because the VS IDE is very comfortable, once you're used to it. But some programming editors allow you to set the configuration to make a backup of the files before you save them (e.g. such as for example [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Backup.html) or [atom](https://discuss.atom.io/t/to-save-a-backup-copy-of-current-file-before-save-it/35391)). The purpose is exactly to prevent the kind of problems that you've just mentioned.
6. The best approach to avoid loosing previous work is of course the source code version control, with the corresponding discipline.  It's easy to setup:  a right-click on your solution in the solution explorer to activate this feature on your project,  then at each significant change, again a right-click on the solution to commit the changes.  With git, you don't even need to create a central repository if you're working alone on smaller projects.  The local repository is sufficient to archive the successive versions of your code and find them back.  But again, it's no magic:  if you've made a lot of changes and didn't commit them, it won't retrieve them...